# JavaScript monkey-patching

Tags: javascript

This code I took from the JS book. I don't get what kind of method I have to pass into this function as an argument(m). It outputs undefined when I do this:

```js
function trace(o, m) {
  var original = o[m]; // Remember original method in the closure.

  o[m] = function() { // Now define the new method.
    console.log(new Date(), "Entering:", m); // Log message.
    var result = original.apply(this, arguments); // Invoke original.
    console.log(new Date(), "Exiting:", m); // Log message.
    return result; // Return result.
  };
}

var a = {
  x: 1,
  y: 2
};

var plus = function(obj) {
  return this.x + this.y;
}
```

Comment: You don't pass a method as argument `m`. You pass a string which the name of a method on object `o`.

Comment: You don't even call `trace`.

Comment: If your obj is like this: `var obj = { x: function(){} }` then your call would look like: `trace(obj, "x")`

Comment: This code is definition only, how can it output something?

Comment: I never seen that pattern before. Usually when decorating functions (that's how it's called in Python), you write a function, that takes a function and *return* function that does something in addition to original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example.

The parameter o has to be an object. The second parameter m is the name of a method in o. The trace method replaces the method in the object. The new method adds some logging and calls the the replaced method.

```js
function trace(o, m) {
    var original = o[m]; // Remember original method in the closure.

    o[m] = function() { // Now define the new method.
        console.log(new Date(), "Entering:", m); // Log message.
        var result = original.apply(this, arguments); // Invoke original.
        console.log(new Date(), "Exiting:", m); // Log message.
        return result; // Return result.
    };
}

var a = {x:1, y:2};

var plus = function (obj) {
    return this.x + this.y;
}
var test = {
 method : plus
}
trace(test, "method");
test.method(a);
```

Comment: Code only answer aren't viewed kindly on stack overflow, you should explain what OP did wrong, and explain what your code do to fix that.

Answer (score 2):

`o` is object, `m` is method name

```js
/**
 * Modifies a given object's property by making it log
 * the enter/exit times of a method call
 * @param {object} o object that has a method that will be called
 * @param {string} m name of the method within the given object
 */
function trace(o, m) {
    var original = o[m]; // Remember original method in the closure.

    o[m] = function() { // Now define the new method.
        console.log(new Date(), "Entering:", m); // Log message.
        var result = original.apply(this, arguments); // Invoke original.
        console.log(new Date(), "Exiting:", m); // Log message.
        return result; // Return result.
    };
}

var obj = {
  doSomething: function() {
      console.log('obj.doSomething was called');
  }
};

// Won't log enter/exit times
obj.doSomething();
trace(obj, "doSomething");
// Will log enter/exit times
obj.doSomething();
```